# How do we reconcile John 5:22 with John 8:15 regarding Christ judging/not judging?

Tags: john

In the Gospel of John, we seem to have what *appears* to be a contradiction:

> **John 5:22**: "For not even the Father judges anyone, but **He has given all judgment to the Son**" (emphasis added).

> **John 8:15**: "You judge according to the flesh; **I [Christ] am not judging anyone**" (emphasis added).

How should we interpret and reconcile these passages?

Answer (score 1):

**How do we reconcile John 5:22 with John 8:15 regarding Christ judging/not judging?**

> John 5:22: "For not even the Father judges anyone, but **He has given
> all judgment to the Son"** (emphasis added).
>
> John 8:15: "You judge according to the flesh; **I [Christ] am not
> judging anyone"** (emphasis added).

God said to his prophet Samuel: “Mere man sees the outward appearance; but as for God, he sees what the heart is .

Samuel 16:7   NASB

> 7 But the Lord said to Samuel, “Do not look at his appearance or at
> the height of his stature, because I have rejected him; for [a]God
> does not see as man sees, since man looks at [b]the outward
> appearance, but the Lord looks at the heart.”

Jesus was sent to earth as a human being,[Flesh -John 6:51, Romans 1:3 John 1:14] He was not sent as a judge in the first century. God however  did later give Jesus the authority to judge, regarding that time of judgment, the prophet Isaiah wrote:

Isaiah 11:3-4 NASB

> 3 And He will delight in the fear of the Lord,  And He will not judge
> by what His eyes see,  Nor make decisions by what His ears hear;  4
> But with righteousness He will judge the poor, And decide with
> fairness for the humble of the earth;  And He will strike the earth
> with the rod of His mouth, And with the breath of His lips He will
> slay the wicked.

The Parable of the sheep and the goads relates to this "Judgement", read:

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+25+%3A31-
46&version=NASB;NET;ESV

Compare  Acts 17;31  , Rev. 20:12-13 , Parable sheep and goats Matthew 25:31-46, 2 Peter 3:7.